# Develop Spring Boot project in a totally off-line environment, is that possible?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Our group wanna reconstruct our old **Spring** project into **Spring Cloud** 
and several **Spring Boot** projects.

And what bothers us is that **we cannot connect to Internet** for some classified & security reasons. We can only download the dependencies at home and take them to our office (this process is very complicate and takes a long time).

I have read some **maven** document in apache website, and got the conclusion that we can't **download** the **whole maven respository**. It is almost impossible for us to download the jars on maven respository one-by-one because they are so many.

For now, we have setup a **nexus server** and **spring boot initializr**, all the problem for now is the maven repository.

Therefore, I wonder if this method is OK or not? Should we quit or is there any other ways?

If you've read this, Thanks.

```
                                       —— An off-line old school programmer
```

Comment: Do you need to add new dependencies in this process? or is it ok to stick with the existing ones? Also, do you have access to the POMs when having a connection to the Internet?

Comment: That is absurd. Let the nexus repo be the only contact with the internet. The repo can be in charge of vetting the artifacts and let only approved ones through, and do a better job than the current process. I work in a secure env too, but this is crazy.

Comment: @user140547 Yes, we need to add new dependencies, existing one is too heavy and too old. I cannot access to the POMs when the Internet is available, but I can remember the POMs and download the dependencies at home, but you know it is a long way to go.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks, but the nexus is totally off-line but an intranet.

Comment: You have my sympathy. Sometimes security bleeds over into stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

You can download all spring framework jars as songle zip according to required spring release [here](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/)

I would suggest you to then upload them to a private repository like Nexus/jfrog and configure all of your Maven/Gradle projects to use this as repository rather than the public repository, This way you don't need access to internet to download dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, 'wget' works on the url you provide. I'll try what you suggest, and I think it will work. BTW, why maven repository forbidden 'wget'? I don't think net work stress is a problem for them.

Comment: @JohnXu well on https://maven.apache.org/community.html they say `DO NOT wget THE ENTIRE REPOSITORY!
Please take only the jars you need. We understand this is may entail more work, but grabbing more than 1,7 TiB of binaries really kills our servers.`

Answer (score 0):

You can download all maven dependencies on nexus server and you have to connect your maven repositories with nexus server for that you just have to provide the configuration in setting.xml(will consist of nexus url) file and have to put xml file in .m2 folder of maven and provide the path in eclipse maven user settings and when you will clean and install the project in eclipse it will automatically download all dependencies from nexus server.

please let me know for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not so difficult for us to get all the dependencies at one time. The situation is that someone need these dependencies today, and others need those dependencies next day, you know.